# Loader only disappears when refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, refresh

I'm trying to do a loader animation while page loads.
I have an index page that as a link/button to the page that I want to have the loader. When I click the link the page opens and runs the loader, but the loader never go away only when I refresh the page. After this everything works fine, the loader always disappears when I open the page.
Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="preloader"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think jQuery's .load is the right method. I think you want [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that! @Benmj

Comment: It doesn't work :/ The loader never disappears even when I refresh the page. But thanks @Benmj

Comment: Hm. Try posting a live code example on a site like JSFiddle. Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and safari @Benmj

Answer (score 0):

Try the same with document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

An assumption here is, your loader is already there in the HTML and is visible by default.

Comment: Can you post a JS fiddle for the same?